# What is the point of a covariant return type in a virtual function?

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism, covariant-return-types

The most common usage of a covariant return type I've seen is via virtual functions. The simplest example I can come up with looks something like this:

```
class Base {
public:
  virtual Base& get() { return *this; }
};


class Derived : public Base {
public:
  Derived& get() override { return *this; }
};
```

One thing I cannot really comprehend is why make these functions virtual. The return type of the `get` function is defined statically at the call point, and there is no way we can get `Derived&` by calling `Base::get` even if `*this` can be downcast to `Derived`. This all means polymorphism won't work for return types anyway. To me it looks a bit more reasonable to make these functions non-virtual and just let the base method get redefined by a child method. But still people prefer making them virtual, at least this is what I've noticed. Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: `clone`  is a more useful example.

Comment: I am afraid your example is too "simple". There is no point in having a `get() { return *this; }` that returns a reference in the first place. And one example that doesnt need a covariant return type doesnt imply that covariant return types are useless in general

Comment: The methods in the example could even have no implementation at all. The point is if you want `Derived&`, you have to use the `Derived` interface, and virtuality does not help here at all. So why would I add some vtable overhead if I could literally remove `virtual` and `override` and just redefine `get` in the `Derived`?

Comment: `Derived d; d.get();` calls `Derived::get` directly; it returns `Derived&`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using more useful example `clone`:

```
class Base {
public:
  virtual ~Base() = default;
  virtual Base* clone() const { return new Base(*this); }
  virtual void print() const { std::cout << "Base\n"; }
};


class Derived : public Base {
public:
  Derived* clone()  const override { return new Derived(*this); }
  void print() const override { std::cout << "Derived\n"; }
  void foo();
};
```

Now, with

```
void clone_and_print(const Base& base)
{
    auto p = base.clone(); // auto is Base*, dynamic type is the same as the one of base
    p->print(); // print Base or Derived
    delete p;
}
```

all is good. removing virtual as you suggest would change the behavior, and print Base unconditionally.

Now, a case when covariant return type is useful:

```
void clone_and_foo(const Derived& derived)
{
    auto p = derived.clone(); // auto is Derived*, not Base*
    p->foo(); // Won't work without covariant return type. would require a cast
    delete p;
}
```

Comment: This is a very illustrative example, thanks. But what would be a rule of thumb for the cases when virtuality does not change the behavior? Should I prefer keeping them virtual or allowing them to redefine one another?

Comment: @Kaiyakha — don’t overthink it. You write virtual functions when you need virtual functions. Occasionally it’s useful for an overriding function to have a covariant return type.

Comment: @Kaiyakha when virtuality does not change the behavior it is sufficient to just have one method in the base class and not override it

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai well, then I can't have a covariant return type from a function with the same name

Comment: @Kaiyakha indeed. No virtual means no covariant return type

Comment: @Kaiyakha polymorphism can be confusing when you look at the implementation only. Once you do encounter a use case, you will understand why you need it. If you dont need it, just dont use a covariant return type. When "when virtuality does not change the behavior" then don't use a virtual function